# Create factories with test environment initiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using `Rspec` with `Factorybot` and I want to create some specific data(and delete it afterwards) **each time before** starting the Rails `test` environment.

For example all my models rely on having a `Manufacturer` and I want to have already created a `Manufacturer` when I start my test environment and have all my factories associate with this specific `Manufacturer` object (its important that its the same object for all factories cause the models have validations for it)?

It worked putting it in the `initializers`:
`if Rails.env.test? { create factories }` but it does not seem like a good idea.

What is the best/cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `before(:each)` block inside the `RSpec.configure` block in your rails_helper.rb or spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :each do
    # create factories here
  end
end
```

This block will then be run before each example.